# 403 Forbidden post request spring boot not working

Tags: spring-boot

I'm having a 403 forbidden request when requesting POST using postman, get is working perfectly and im not using any of spring security tools just spring boot because i have seen some answers talking about disabling csrf which is not my case because im not using any of spring security.

Here is My Entity class:

```
   package com.example.demo.entity;

   import java.util.Date;
   import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
   import javax.persistence.Table;
   import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
   import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


   @Entity
   @Table(name="clients")
   public class Clients {

    @Id
    @Column(name="phone")
    private Long phone;

    @NotBlank(message="Required Field")
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @NotBlank(message="Required Field") 
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @NotBlank(message="Required Field") 
    @Column(name="birthDate")
    private String birthDate;

    @NotBlank(message="Required Field") 
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message="Required Field") 
    @Column(name="addressClient")
    private String addressClient;

    @NotBlank(message="Required Field") 
    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;


    @Column(name="inscriptionDate")
    private Date inscriptionDate;

    @NotBlank(message="Required Field") 
    @Size(min=8 , message="Password needs to be more than 8 characters")
    @Column(name="passwordClient")
    private String passwordClient;


    public Clients() {

    }



    public Clients(Long phone, @NotBlank(message = "Required Field") String firstname,
            @NotBlank(message = "Required Field") String lastname,
            @NotBlank(message = "Required Field") String birthDate, @NotBlank(message = "Required Field") String email,
            @NotBlank(message = "Required Field") String addressClient,
            @NotBlank(message = "Required Field") String gender, Date inscriptionDate,
            @NotBlank(message = "Required Field") @Size(min = 8, message = "Password needs to be more than 8 characters") String passwordClient) {
        super();
        this.phone = phone;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.email = email;
        this.addressClient = addressClient;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.inscriptionDate = inscriptionDate;
        this.passwordClient = passwordClient;
    }



    @PrePersist
    public void newDate() {
        this.inscriptionDate=new Date();
    }

    public Long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddressClient() {
        return addressClient;
    }

    public void setAddressClient(String addressClient) {
        this.addressClient = addressClient;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Date getInscriptionDate() {
        return inscriptionDate;
    }

    public void setInscriptionDate(Date inscriptionDate) {
        this.inscriptionDate = inscriptionDate;
    }

    public String getPasswordClient() {
        return passwordClient;
    }

    public void setPasswordClient(String passwordClient) {
        this.passwordClient = passwordClient;
    }
    }
```

And Here s my Repository Interface:

```
    package com.example.demo.repositories;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.example.demo.entity.Clients;

    @Repository
    public interface ClientsRepository extends JpaRepository<Clients , Long>{
    }
```

My Controller Class:

```
     package com.example.demo.controllers;

     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Optional;

     import javax.validation.Valid;

     import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
     import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
     import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

     import com.example.demo.entity.Clients;
     import com.example.demo.functions.ClientsFunctionsImpl;
     import com.example.demo.repositories.ClientsRepository;



   @RestController
   public class ClientsController {

   @Autowired
   private ClientsRepository clientsRepository;


   @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
   @GetMapping(path="/clientslist")
   public List<Clients> getAllClients(){

     return clientsfunctionsimpl.list();

   }



   @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
   @PostMapping("/clientslist")
   public ResponseEntity<Clients> createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Clients client) {

    Clients client1 = clientsRepository.save(client);

    return new ResponseEntity<Clients>(client1,HttpStatus.CREATED);
   }
   }
```

Comment: It seems that you're passing model save that model and gave reference to an instance of that model. Please try to use the model and metamodel concept for creating anything.

Comment: I test this everything is working fine albeit My advice to you that use ClientsModel for taking data and use ClientsMetaModel for saving data it is quite useful and it also prevents from SQL injection.

Comment: it is working when i removed the @CrossOrigin annotation and doesnt when i use the CrossOrigin("/*") but im using react as frontend and i m gonna need that CrossOrigin somehow to prevent no access error how am i going to manage that :/

Answer (score 0):

Could you try enabling CORS on all ports and url for your endpoint like :

```
  @CrossOrigin
   @PostMapping("/clientslist")
   public ResponseEntity<Clients> createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Clients client) {

    Clients client1 = clientsRepository.save(client);

    return new ResponseEntity<Clients>(client1,HttpStatus.CREATED);
   }
```

Comment: It is working when i removed the @CrossOrigin annotation and doesnt when i use the CrossOrigin("/*") but im using react as frontend and i m gonna need that CrossOrigin somehow to prevent no access error how am i going to manage that :/

Comment: @FayçalMekdour Sorry it was a mistake from my part, to allow cross origin on all origins just put the annotation without passing in value as the default setting allows all origins. But you could just add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")` and try again if you want to just allow localhost.

Comment: @FayçalMekdour Try setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as the `http://localhost:3000` in your postman request header.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working but I want to add one more thing is that use this type of structure it will prevent SQL injection and improve your creation API response.

```java
        @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
        @PostMapping(value = "/createEmployee")
        public ResponseEntity<ClientsMetaModel> createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody ClintsModel model) {
            ClientsMetaModel metaModel = new ClientsMetaModel();
            // set all your fields into metamodel by getting it from model
            return new ResponseEntity<ClientsMetaModel>(empRepo.save(metaModel), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
```

You have to kept your `id`, `token`, `date` all fields into **metamodel** only and try this.
If this will not work then use `@CrossOrigin(/*)` as global. Also as @Ananthapadmanabhan said in his answer but I advise you that use model and metamodel concept.

Comment: it is working when i removed the @CrossOrigin annotation and doesnt when i use the CrossOrigin("/*") but im using react as frontend and i m gonna need that CrossOrigin somehow to prevent no access error how am i going to manage that :/

Comment: I am a little bit confused. You mean to say that you are calling your API using reactjs and you have to restrict origin for that only?

Comment: Yess im using the Cross origin annotation to enable cross origin sharing from my react fronend to the spring boot backend but since i ve removed it now i will for sure get that cross origin error